# AppIcon not displayed in Xcode organiser

Tags: xcode, ios9

I updated an existing iPad app to iOS 9. 
When archiving it no AppIcon shows up in organiser (I see the appIcon placeholder)
I added the missing 87.5@2x file for iPad pro.
When installing to the Simulator the icon of the app is displayed correctly. Also on a real iPad mini.
Cleaning the project didn't help.

I don't think it's because of changes made in the update, since when I load the code from the last release without changes it doesn't show up either.

I'm running xCode 7.2 (7C68)

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I just saw your question - maybe the same problem. I assume you tried the suggested answers without success !?

Comment: nope not yet, are you building natively?

Comment: @bobo2000 Well, then I'll probably give it a go. Yes, I'm building natively.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with XCode 9.0, a project that worked perfectly well under XCode 8 and iOS 10 suddenly loses it's icons (only on iPads) when I upgraded the solution.

Tore my hair out, did the sRGB thing, did the Transparency thing.

Turns out I still had the following empty entry in my targets info.plist file

CFBundleIcons~ipad

I'd long ago moved to specifying this in the target build settings.

The solution was to simpy remove this entry from the info.plist file (clicked the helpfull little "-" button. Rebuilt and tested and everything was perfect once more.